# Fill null values in dataframe column with next value

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have to fill the first null values with immediate value of the same column in dataframe. This logic applies only on first consecutive null values only of the column.

I have a dataframe with similar to below

```
 //I replaced null to 0 in value column
 val df = Seq( (0,"exA",30), (0,"exB",22), (0,"exC",19), (16,"exD",13),
               (5,"exE",28), (6,"exF",26), (0,"exG",12), (13,"exH",53))
               .toDF("value", "col2", "col3")

scala> df.show(false)
+-----+----+----+
|value|col2|col3|
+-----+----+----+
|0    |exA |30  |
|0    |exB |22  |
|0    |exC |19  |
|16   |exD |13  |
|5    |exE |28  |
|6    |exF |26  |
|0    |exG |12  |
|13   |exH |53  |
+-----+----+----+
```

From this dataframe I am expecting as below

```
scala> df.show(false)
+-----+----+----+
|value|col2|col3|
+-----+----+----+
|16   |exA |30  |    // Change the value 0 to 16 at value column
|16   |exB |22  |    // Change the value 0 to 16 at value column
|16   |exC |19  |    // Change the value 0 to 16 at value column
|16   |exD |13  |
|5    |exE |28  |
|6    |exF |26  |
|0    |exG |12  |    // value should not be change here
|13   |exH |53  |
+-----+----+----+
```

Please help me solve this.

Comment: Hello @Rao does the dataset have a unique column? or the combination of them as a whole is unique for each row?

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis combination all of the columns will be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Window function for this purpose

```
 val df = Seq( (0,"exA",30), (0,"exB",22), (0,"exC",19), (16,"exD",13),
           (5,"exE",28), (6,"exF",26), (0,"exG",12), (13,"exH",53))
           .toDF("value", "col2", "col3")
 val w = Window.orderBy($"col2".desc)
 df.withColumn("Result", last(when($"value" === 0, null).otherwise($"value"), ignoreNulls = true).over(w))
  .orderBy($"col2")
  .show(10)
```

Will result in

```
+-----+----+----+------+
|value|col2|col3|Result|
+-----+----+----+------+
|    0| exA|  30|    16|
|    0| exB|  22|    16|
|    0| exC|  19|    16|
|   16| exD|  13|    16|
|    5| exE|  28|     5|
|    6| exF|  26|     6|
|    0| exG|  12|    13|
|   13| exH|  53|    13|
+-----+----+----+------+
```

Expression `df.orderBy($"col2")` is needed only to show final results in right order. You can skip it if you don't care about final order.

**UPDATE**
To get exactly what you need you should you a little bit more complicated code

```
val w = Window.orderBy($"col2")
val w2 = Window.orderBy($"col2".desc)
df.withColumn("IntermediateResult", first(when($"value" === 0, null).otherwise($"value"), ignoreNulls = true).over(w))
  .withColumn("Result", when($"IntermediateResult".isNull, last($"IntermediateResult", ignoreNulls = true).over(w2)).otherwise($"value"))
  .orderBy($"col2")
    .show(10)

+-----+----+----+------------------+------+
|value|col2|col3|IntermediateResult|Result|
+-----+----+----+------------------+------+
|    0| exA|  30|              null|    16|
|    0| exB|  22|              null|    16|
|    0| exC|  19|              null|    16|
|   16| exD|  13|                16|    16|
|    5| exE|  28|                16|     5|
|    6| exF|  26|                16|     6|
|    0| exG|  12|                16|     0|
|   13| exH|  53|                16|    13|
+-----+----+----+------------------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take the 1st not null or non-zero value based on col2 's order. Please find the script below. I have created a table in spark's memory to write sql.

```
val df = Seq( (0,"exA",30), (0,"exB",22), (0,"exC",19), (16,"exD",13),
               (5,"exE",28), (6,"exF",26), (0,"exG",12), (13,"exH",53))
               .toDF("value", "col2", "col3")
df.registerTempTable("table_df")
spark.sql("with cte as(select *,row_number() over(order by col2) rno from table_df) select case when value = 0 and rno<(select min(rno) from cte where value != 0) then (select value from cte where rno=(select min(rno) from cte where value != 0)) else value end value,col2,col3 from cte").show(df.count.toInt,false)
```

[image]

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you. Can we get by using spark functions

Comment: Yes, we can also use scala code to acheive this but will be more complex. If you write in scala code or write sql as I did, both works on top of spark

Answer (score -1):

I added a new column with incremental id to your DF

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._    
val df_1 = Seq((0,"exA",30),
    (0,"exB",22), 
    (0,"exC",19), 
    (16,"exD",13),  
    (5,"exE",28), 
    (6,"exF",26), 
    (0,"exG",12), 
    (13,"exH",53))
    .toDF("value", "col2", "col3")
    .withColumn("UniqueID", monotonically_increasing_id)
```

filter DF to have non-zero values

```
val df_2 = df_1.filter("value != 0")
```

create a variable "limit" to limit first N row that we need and variable Nvar for the first non-zero value

```
val limit = df_2.agg(min("UniqueID")).collect().map(_(0)).mkString("").toInt + 1
val nVal = df_1.limit(limit).agg(max("value")).collect().map(_(0)).mkString("").toInt
```

create DF with a column with the same name ("value") with a condition

```
val df_4 = df_1.withColumn("value", when(($"UniqueID" < limit), nVal).otherwise($"value"))
```

Comment: we should not take maximum of the value, we have to take immediate next non zero/null value. here `nVal` calculation is would not return proper value

Comment: Yep, my fault. Fixed